# javascript function with parameters in function-call possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

Does following call make sense / is it even possible?

```
    getCall('GET', URL, null, function(x, status, jqXHR){ }, failedRes);



     function getCall(method, url, data, func, func2){
        .ajax({
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: data,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json"
          }).done(function(data, textStatus,jqXHR) {
                console.log("done");
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                console.log("fail");
            });
   } 

    function func2(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        window.alert("AJAX call error occured");
        console.error( errorThrown );
    }
```

I wonder most because of the "{}", but also because of the parameters.
Is the function-parameter "function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ }" too much? Rather the {} not correct?

Comment: It makes no sense if you pass in a function but then don't use it like you've done here.

Comment: So the 'function(x, status, jqXHR){ }' should be taken additionally to the jquery-done-callback? If I write in the function like this, where would if be? I add the "..." of the ajax in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function(x, status, jqXHR){ }` defines a function which can be called, but when it is called it doesn't do anything except returning `undefined`. In some situation, this might be intentional.

In this case I wonder why that parameter exists at all, because `getCall` doesn't even use the parameter `func`.

Comment: This was my thought too, this is why I wanted to forward my question;).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything in. Personally, I like to set up data passing in a more structured manner just in case, in the future, things need to be updated. Passing function references or functions themselves is totally doable.

ala:

```
var data = {
   call: "GET",
   url: URL,
   data: null,
   func: function(x, status,jqXHR){},
   func2: failedRes
}

getCall(data);


function getCall(data){
   data = data || {};

   // then just access your vars like so: data.url
```

Comment: I know you can pass in function. Isn't the passed in function actually the "done"-callback? Wouldn't this be double then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works.

```
function callFunction(func, param) {
    return func(param);
}
callFunction(
    function(a) {
        return a*2;
    },
    2
);
```

returns `4`

Answer (score 0):

This is JavaScript AJAX request/response format:

```
function xhr(method, url, send, success){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var v = send ? encodeURI(send) : null;
  method = method.toUpperCase();
  x.open(method, url);
  if(method.match(/^POST$/)){
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-length', v.length); x.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
  }
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      success(x.responseText);
    }
  }
  x.send(v);
}
```